# Is there a word for a multi-user attempt to grab something?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

I'm looking for a word (or phrase) that describes the actions of the hippos in the game of Hungry Hungry Hippos.

> All 20 guests saw that there were only 5 shrimp left and what ensued
>   was a frenzied [SOMETHING].

Is there such a word (or colloquialism) in the English language?

Comment: Try "gobbling" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head:  grabfest.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks!